# Elaborating some points in the proof of Proposition 3 on pg.100 "Royden and Fitzpatrick 4th edition"

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The proposition and its proof are given below:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- why is $|f_{n} - f| < \eta$ and not $<\epsilon$?

2- why is $\{x \in E | |f_{n} - f(x)| > \eta \} \subseteq (E \setminus F)$?

Could anyone help me in finding answers to those questions, please?

Comment: 1. is just a definition. For 2. read the the line $|f_n-f|<\eta$ on $F$ for all $n\geq N$. So for $n\geq N$ and $y\in F$ we can't have $|f_n(y)-f(y)|\geq \eta$. So any $x\in E$ with $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\eta$ implies $x$ is outside of $F$.

Comment: @S.D. 1. why $\eta$ and not $\epsilon$?

Comment: I do not know @S.D.

Comment: I think in your first comment in the last line the second inequality should be reversed

Comment: Yeah you are right.

Comment: No, you are not right, the first one should be $\eta$

Comment: So please state your definition of convergence in measure??

Comment: it is stated in the picture in $(4)$@S.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a confusing thing here is that, technically, there should be written

- $|f_n - f| \color{blue}{\leq} \eta$ on $F$ for all $n \geq N$

if one takes the definition of convergence in measure as given in the book:

For all $\eta > 0$ we have

- $\lim_{n\to\infty}m\left(\{x \in E\, | \, |f_n(x) - f(x)| \color{blue}{>} \eta\}\right) = 0$

Now, fix an arbitrary $\eta>0$. Hence, to show is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $m\left(\{x \in E\, | \, |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \eta\}\right) < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

So, let $\epsilon >0$. Then [Egorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem#The_formal_statement_of_the_theorem_and_its_proof) assures that $f_n \Rightarrow f$ **on an** $\pmb{F \subseteq E}$ such that $m(E\setminus F) < \epsilon$. So, there is an $N$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \color{blue}{\leq} \eta$ for $n \geq N$ **on** $\pmb{F}$. This in turn means, that 
$\{x \in E\, | \, |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \eta\} \subseteq E\setminus F$ **for all** $\pmb{n \geq N}$.

Hence $m\left(\{x \in E\, | \, |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \eta\}\right) \leq m(E \setminus F) < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.